# how to render each item in an array after every three seconds with waiting animations in between in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, algorithm, events

suppose I have a List component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class List extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            list: [1, 2, 3, 5]
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <ul>
                <li>{this.state.list}</li>
            </ul>
        );
    }

}

export default List;
```

my desired output is to display '1', then display '...' for three seconds to mimic 'loading', and when three seconds is up, hide '...' and display 2, then display '...' for three seconds and so on until it displays 5. so the final output will look like:

```
1

2

3

4

5
```

please guide me. Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: i tried setTimeout, but I couldn't get the toggling between '...' and displaying the digits working @Treycos

Comment: You should provide a [mcve]. any way, a short answer, just don't start with `list: [1, 2, 3, 5]`. instead start with an empty array and update it every second (with `setInterval` etc..)

Comment: Yes. But why I posted it here is because I want to get the switching between '...' and displaying digits every three seconds working @Sagivb.g

Comment: Then just add another boolean flag and conditionally render the loader

Answer (score 0):

I feel that this could have been googled or whatever before posting here on SO.

However, is this the behavior that you want?

```
import React from "react";

class State {
    list: any[];
}

class List extends React.Component<{}, State> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            list: []
        };

        let intervalCount = 0;
        let self = this;

        let arr = self.state.list;
        let interval = setInterval(function() {
            intervalCount++;
            arr.push(intervalCount);
            self.setState({
                list: arr
            });

            if (intervalCount == 5) {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, 3000);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.state.list.map(function(item, index) {
                    return <li key={index}>{item}</li>;
                })}
                <li>...</li>
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

export default List;
```